# Creating index for DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I insert an incremental index in a dataframe, or reassign/realign existing index items.

Currently I have in my dataframe is:
df.head(4)

```
------------------
|         |amount|
------------------
|id       |      |
-----------------
|cb782ea3 |  3750|
------------------
|bhek8s9  |   900|
------------------
|hdci39w  |  3450|
```

And what I need is either:

```
------------------
|id       |amount|
-----------------
|cb782ea3 |  3750|
------------------
|bhek8s9  |   900|
------------------
|hdci39w  |  3450|
```

OR

```
-----------------------
|    |id       |amount|
-----------------------
|0   |cb782ea3 |  3750|
----------------------
|1   |bhek8s9  |   900|
-----------------------
|2   |hdci39w  |  3450|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the index with:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

This will reassign the Id as well.